# Im having an issue chaining Tasks

Tags: c#

I have two main async methods (http requests) that need to be completed over and over again. Along with one regular method inbetween those.

I want it so that it first fires GetContact() as fast as it can for all objects.

Then when GetContact() gets completed for each object (however long that may be) it will automatically call UpdateContact() for that object.

All of them passing in the results of the previous operation along the way.

```
foreach(Contact objContact in listContacts)
{
   Task<Contact> Task1 = GetContact(email);
   Task1.Start();

   Task1.ContinueWith(OverwriteData(Task1.Result));

   Task1.ContinueWith(UpdateContact(Task1.Result.Result));

}

Wait AllTasks; //PsuedoCode that stands for 'wait for everything to finish'.
```

I'm absolutely positive I am setting up my tasks wrong, along with my methods->

```
public async static Task<Contact> GetContact(string EMAIL)
{
  Contact Data = await HttpRequest 10.0.0.1
  return Data;
}

//This one is NOT asynchronous by nature
public static bool OverWriteData(Contact objContact)
{
   objContact.Data = NewData;
   return true;
}

public async static Task<bool> UpdateContact(Contact objContact)
{
   HttpPost 10.0.0.2 (objContact.JsonData)
   if(Success) { return true; }
   
   else{ return false;}
}
```

I've been struggling trying to figure out how I should be formatting this. Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** So first it grabs the single contacts data from a server, overwrites it with the data on our end, and then submits it back to the same server with the new data instead.

I want it asynchronous because if we try to do this with 30 contacts, and its synchronous, then I'm waiting a whole lot unnecessarily and it takes a lot longer.

---

**EDIT 2:** All I want to do is have a task know that it needs to call another task (or even method) after completing, if I can get THAT working then I can probably figure out the rest.

Comment: Why `.Result` why not `await` it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the use of `ContinueWith`. Just execute them in order in ordinary code, awaiting each step. Wrap in a single method for convenience.

```
async Task DoItAll(string email)
{
    var contact = await GetContact(email);
    var ok = await OverwriteData(contact);
    await UpdateContact(contact);
}
```

Now execute this wrapper method for each contact, and await the whole list.

```
var tasks = listContacts.Select(DoItAll).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I suppose I could stuff it all inside one big method... It just seems like that method is going to get very very bloated and hard to debug once I start adding in error handling and  branching results, etc.

All I want to do is have a task call another task after completing, if I can get THAT working then I can probably figure out the rest.

Comment: What he's suggesting is that you keep your methods as they are and wrap them in an additional convenience method. His answer will get you what you want albeit in a different way than you expected.

Comment: John Wu, and or @AndreaScarcella . What is the purpose of listContacts.Select(DoItAll).ToList() ?     I have a list<string> called listContacts and it doesn't know what .Select() means

Comment: Select(DoItAll) will apply the DoItAll method to all elements of input List. This is a shorthand for 

.Select(q=>DoItAll(q))

Comment: [Linq's `Select` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @JohnWu Ah yes, I was missing Linq. 

So I'm correct that this code would let me start the process for 30 contacts, roughly all at the same time, and then all 30 contacts will be doing their own overwrite and update process independently of each other, right?

Comment: Yes. Everything within `DoItAll` is performed in series. All instances of `DoItAll` happen in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use await and do like this:

```
public async Task GetAndUpdateContact(string email)
{
    Contact contact = await GetContact(email);
    OverwriteData(contact);
    await UpdateContact(contact);
}
```

Then:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (Contact objContact in listContacts)
{
    tasks.Add(GetAndUpdateContact(objContact.Email));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I like this code, even though it is similar to the other answer.

So this code would let me start the process for 30 contacts, roughly all at the same time, and then all 30 contacts will be doing their own overwrite and update process independently of each other?